# Prove that, given a graph G, if χ(G) ≥ 6, then there must exist at least two odd cycles that do not share a vertex

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to go about this question by proving the contrapositive: If a graph does not have at least two odd cycles that do not share a vertex, then prove χ(G) < 6  . (χ(G) is the minimum number of colors needed to color the vertices of G where no two adjacent vertices have the same color)

I dont know how to proceed from here. I was thinking of maybe using the fact that graphs without odd cycles are bipartite and therefore 2-colorable.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* Pick the shortest odd cycle $C$, and color all the vertices in $C$. Then color all the other vertices.

(This approach doesn't make sense if there's no odd cycles at all, but you know how to handle that case.)

Comment: How would I use this to determine if the graph is less than 6-colorable though?

Comment: Use only 3 colors for the first step, and only 2 colors for the second step.